# how to combine multiple rows into one row with same column value v1 in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

`View_ID` and `MAC_QR_Code` are common in multiple rows but `Button_ID` is different. What I want when retrieving `View_ID` it should be treated as single `v1` and on Image click event view all three `Button_ID`.
**Insert Query**
[image]

```
 public void insertData(String view_id, String button_id, String publish_topic, String subscribe_topic, byte[] image, String qr_code){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO CONFIG VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(1, view_id);
    statement.bindString(2, button_id);
    statement.bindString(3, publish_topic);
    statement.bindString(4, subscribe_topic);
    statement.bindBlob(5, image);
    statement.bindString(6, qr_code);


    statement.executeInsert();
}
```

**Get All data from SQLite**

```
  // get all data from SQLite
    Cursor cursor =sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM CONFIG");
    GetAdapter1.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String view_id = cursor.getString(1);
        String button_id = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(5);

        GetAdapter1.add(new GetAdapter(view_id, button_id, image, id));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on it quite long now I saw that in SQLite we have to use select command